# fullCalendar - Disable Multiselect Day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I would like to disable multi selection day in fullCalendar.Can be selected only one day. I searched in here and fullCalendar website but I did not find exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/opqdqLa0/

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  editable: true,
    selectable: true,
  //header and other values
  select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      if(end.getTime() != start.getTime()){
          calendar.fullCalendar( 'unselect' ) ;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: But it will unselect the day which selected before

Comment: You can store the previously selected date and reselect if the multi dates are chosen. http://jsfiddle.net/opqdqLa0/23/

Comment: I have tried this way. However, the stack will be crashed. Beacause reselect the previously one will fire the select callback and then it will invoke reselect... code snippets like belowing:

`select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      if(end.getTime() != start.getTime()){
          calendar.fullCalendar( 'unselect' ) ;
      }else{
          calendar.fullCalendar( 'select', previousOne ) ;
      }
   }`